# Python Hive: thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: None

Tags: python, hive

Suppose Hive is installed in say, "g" cluster. I do not have access to the Gold Cluster. I'm doing my python development work in "s" cluster. I can access Hive from the "s" cluster and run queries.

I have the below code to connect to Hive from a Python script running in "s" cluster.

`some_table` is a table that already exists in Hive. I would like to execute a simple `select * from some_table` command to get some results.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/hive/lib/py")

from hive_service import ThriftHive
from hive_service.ttypes import HiveServerException
from thrift import Thrift
from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol


transport = TSocket.TSocket('what-ever-server', what-ever-port)
transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)

client = ThriftHive.Client(protocol)
transport.open()
print "connect success"
client.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table")
print client.fetchAll()
print "executed"
```

But I get the below error after "connect success" is printed. I am assuming that the connection was successful.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "hiveConnect.py", line 30, in <module>
      row = client.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table")
   File "/usr/lib/hive/lib/py/hive_service/ThriftHive.py", line 68, in execute
      self.recv_execute()
   File "/usr/lib/hive/lib/py/hive_service/ThriftHive.py", line 79, in recv_execute
       (fname, mtype, rseqid) = self._iprot.readMessageBegin()
   File "/usr/lib/hive/lib/py/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 137, in readMessageBegin
       name = self.trans.readAll(sz)
   File "/usr/lib/hive/lib/py/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 58, in readAll
        chunk = self.read(sz-have)
   File "/usr/lib/hive/lib/py/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 155, in read
        self.__rbuf = StringIO(self.__trans.read(max(sz, self.DEFAULT_BUFFER)))
   File "/usr/lib/hive/lib/py/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 94, in read
        raise TTransportException('TSocket read 0 bytes')
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: None
```

What am I doing wrong in this code? I am not experiencing any error while connecting to Hive using the server-name and port, so I'm assuming everything is fine there and that the connection to Hive is not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after a bit more research I found that it was actually HiveServer2 that was being used with a port number of 10,000. After that I had to install pyhs2 for it to work properly.